# git not pushing all files within folder

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to add, commit and push all folders and files to a branch, I have tried :

```
git add -A
git commit -m "version7"
git push origin develop
```

and

```
git add .
git commit -m "version7"
git push origin develop
```

and

```
git add *
git commit -m "version7"
git push origin develop
```

But it's not pushing every single file I have in my local folders. What could be wrong? I have checked that nothing is ignored too.

Comment: If you have empty directories and you were not able to commit them, everything is okay. Git tracks files and not folders.

Comment: but there are folders with files that don't commit

Comment: which server are you using ? is it bitbucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if your files are being ignored by using [`git-check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
$ git check-ignore /c/your/directory/your_file.txt
```

If there is output there in the form of the analyzed file, then that file is effectively being ignored.  If there is *no* output, then in that case the file is not matching an ignore pattern.

Something I personally find helpful with `git-check-ignore` is to specify `--verbose` so that you can see which gitignore is causing the matching entry (i.e. global or local to the repo), as well as the pattern that is actually matching the ignore specification.  Also specifying `-n` will give you non-matching entries as well (instead of the "blank"), so that you can visually see and verify that there is no match to an ignore specification.

```
$ git check-ignore /c/your/directory/your_file.txt --verbose -n
```

A ***non-matching file*** (not-ignored file) would show this:

```
::      C:/your/directory/your_file.txt
```

A ***matching file*** (ignored file) would show like this:

```
.gitignore:1:*.txt     C:/your/directory/your_file.txt
```

The verbosity here shows the local `.gitignore`, the line number in the file, as well as the pattern matching the ignore specification (in this case, the pattern is `*.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
git add .
git commit -am "version7"
git push origin develop
```

These code commits the added and modified files.

Comment: Shouldn't git add . do the same thing as git commit -am as it pertains to adding all files?  I believe git commit -am let's you do a git add and commit message all in one.

Comment: didn't work doesn't commit or push all files on my local folders

Comment: I always use `git add`.  According to the docs the -a (or --all) option does not add new files.  Has that changed?

Answer (score 0):

What files is it not including?  I assume that they are not part of the commit, but please verify that.  You mentioned the ignore, but have you looked at all the `.gitignore` files?

Comment: where is .gitignore ?

Comment: It can be a couple of places.  Take a look at the documentation http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Type `git ls-files -o` to see if the files are ignored. If ignored, you will see their names in the output.

In order to start tracking previously ignored files or patterns:

1. You need to change your working directory to the repository by typing `cd <path>`.
2. You need to specify the files or patterns to track them by typing `git add -f <file name>.extension` for a specific file or `git add -f *.png` for all png files.